# CSS Alignment Issue in blocks

Tags: css, alignment

Need a little assistance.

Click  [here](http://nerdthemes.co/hk/demo/sellers.php) and scroll down to Print Marketing block...those 4 blocks have to be side by side but the 4th one is going down for some reason...

Here is the block of code for that area

```
<div class="eleven columns bottom-4">
    <h3 class="title">Print Marketing</h3>
<div class="five columns item element-2">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/img/sellers/slide1a.png" alt="" class="pic" />
    </a>
</div>
<!-- End -->

<!-- item 2 -->
<div class="five columns item element-2">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/img/sellers/slide1b.png" alt="" class="pic" />
    </a>
</div>
<!-- End -->
<!-- item 3 -->
<div class="five columns item element-2">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/img/sellers/slide1a.png" alt="" class="pic" />
    </a>
</div>
<!-- End -->

<!-- item 4 -->
<div class="five columns item element-2">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/img/sellers/slide1b.png" alt="" class="pic" />
    </a>
</div>
<!-- End -->


  </div>
```

CSS is as follows..

```
.container .columns {
float: left;
display: inline;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
.container .five.columns {
width: 280px;
}
.container .eleven.columns {
width: 640px;
}
```

I have tried many things on it. Even gave them an inline style which doesnt work either...Any ideas on this because all of them have the same class that is applied to them but one block whacks all of the rest.

Let me know thanks.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: It's because your second image is not the same height as the first.

Comment: the size of the image was the real issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You could always try to nest the divs within a table, if you're trying to align them to a grid like that.

Answer (score 0):

On the third div block, you need to add `clear:left;` (either inline or via a class).